# How to get module from another directory from terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

this is in Python, python 3.10.2 if we need specifics.

I’m using the Mac Terminal and I want to access a folder from it

I have a folder on my desktop that has a bunch of my modules. I wanna access these from the terminal in a style like: “import module” with using some command to get to that folder.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `import sys`, then `sys.path.append(path_to_desired_modules)`. `sys.path` is a list of the directories where Python will search for the modules to import, so if you append the target directory to that, it should be retrievable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Could you show me just like an example syntax of the syspathappend thing?

Comment: It would be "import sys" at the beginning to make sys available, then "sys.path.append(path_to_desired_modules)" and then "import desired_modules".

Comment: And also nvm I figured it out lol. Just was forgetting how file navigation works. Thanks so much bro

Comment: Oh yeah another thing. Is this command permanent? Like if I were to close out and do it again would it be kept? Or would I have to type it in again

Comment: sys.path.append() is in memory only, it doesn't move the file around on your drive. But you can, of course, re-run the same code next time you execute the program.